# Flyway doesn't update schema history

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, flyway

I try to use flyway in my spring-boot project. I use flyway-core 7.9.1, ojdbc8 and Oracle 19.0.

But when I start program, the `flyway_schema_history table` doesn't update. The version of schema keeps in 1. Here is the log.

```
Current version of schema "COMPS": 1
Schema "COMPS" is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

My script location is like

[image]

`spring.flyway.locations=classpath:/db/migration/local/${sprint.version}`
Could anybody help me figure out the issue? Thank you so much.
Please let me know if need more information.

Comment: Not sure if it helps but you could try to replace the underscore in the version with a dot (e.g. `V.1.60.0_1` → `V.1.60.0.1`).

Comment: @slauth I change version to `V1.9.0_1` and it success. Really strange... Thanks for your help!